# Windows phone crash when loading rss feed

Tags: windows-phone-8, rss, windows-phone, linq-to-xml

I got some code to load rss feeds to my WindowsPhone app:

```
var result = e.Result;
    result = result.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
    result = result.Replace("\n", string.Empty);

    var rssItems = XDocument.Parse(result.Replace("dc:creator", "creator")).Descendants("item").Select(
         x => new RssItem()
              {
                  Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                  Description = (string)x.Element("description"),
                  Link = (string)x.Element("link"),
                  Author = (string)x.Element("creator"),
                  Comments = (string)x.Element("comments"),
                  PubDate = ParseNewsDateToStringFormatExtended(Convert.ToDateTime((string)x.Element("pubDate"))),
                  ThumbnailPart = stripImagePathFromDescription((string)x.Element("description").Value.ToString()),
                  StrippedHtml = strippedHtmlConversion((string)x.Element("title"), (string)x.Element("creator"), ParseNewsDateToStringFormatExtended(Convert.ToDateTime((string)x.Element("pubDate"))), (string)x.Element("description").Value.ToString())
                                    }
                                ).ToList();
                        success(rssItems);
```

When it loads feeds containing this symbol « or » it crashes. How can i make my app able to read these symbols?

EDIT: here is one element from my rss feed:

```
<item>
   <title>Norges «skjulte perle» utvider</title>
```

As you can see there a «» in the title of the item. And i know that's why it crashes. But why? And how to handle these symbols?

Comment: Please provide an sample of the data on which it crashes.

Comment: See updated answer. i Couldn't link the entire item cause it auto converted a lot of symbols so it really just got unreadable.

Comment: Have you tried `result = result.Replace("«", string.Empty);` and `result = result.Replace("»", string.Empty);` ?